# How to retrieve email from sent (google api)

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I want to get an email from my gmail sent items via c#.
I used this

```
service.Users.Messages.Get("me",id);
```

but it get 404 error.
All other apis works properly.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

404 means that the Id you are requesting does not exist.  I would run a List first then a get after.

If you want to see messages that are in the sent folder you should do a [message.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list?apix_params=%7B%22userId%22%3A%22me%22%2C%22q%22%3A%22is%3Asent%22%7D)
and search for what is in the sent folder.

```
var request = service.Users.Messages.List("me");
request.Q = "is:sent";
var result = request.Execute();
```

If you know when it was sent you could add a date.

```
var request = service.Users.Messages.List("me");
request.Q = "is:sent  after:2021/3/28 before:2021/3/31";
var result = request.Execute();
```

Tip Q works just like the search function in the Gmail web application so if you can get that to return what you want just add it to Q

[image]